# Outlook 2016 Does Not Continue Receiving and Sending Emails When Open

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2016

I am using Outlook 2016 (Office 2016 Pro) on a Windows 10 desktop.
I have been using this since July, 2020 without any problems.

Starting about 3 weeks ago these problems started:
When Outlook is already open, it **sometimes** stops receiving messages.  I know there are at least some messages to receive because I have sent them with my mobile phone.  They are not in my Junk E-mail folder.
Also, **sometimes** messages I send in Outlook just sit in the Outbox (over 15 minutes) until I close and re-open Outlook.

Thus, I have to close and re-open Outlook to get it to start receiving messages again and send what is in the Outbox.
When I re-open Outlook, sometimes it asks for my email password and sometimes it does not ask.

Things I have tried:
I have googled but not found anything about it.

I have called Costco Concierge (I bought my PC from Costco), who told me I had to call Microsoft support and gave me a number to call.  However when I called the #, I received a message that I had to search their site.  I was not able to talk with anyone.  I did search but did not find anything to help.

I have a Best Buy Geek Squad support contract, so I called them and they took control of my PC to look at things.  Unfortunately, while they were attached Outlook worked normally.  The problem is **intermittent**.

Answer (score 0):

What's the version of your Outlook 2016(File>Office account>About Outlook), please first ensure that you have installed the latest update of Outlook.

Considering the issue occurred only recently, have you performed any specific operations before it(such as install any program or add-ins)?

In order to avoid the interference of add-ins, it's suggested to restart your Outlook in safe mode to check if the issue has any difference(Windows + R> type "Outlook.exe /safe"> enter )

If the issue still exists, as I know the corrupted data file or send/receive file may also affect the send/receive of message, you could also try to create a new Outlook profile and re-add your account to check, which would create new data file and send/receive file automatically.(Control Panel>Mail>Show profiles>Add>type a new profile name>re-add your account)

Hope that would be helpful to you.

Comment: Outlook 2016 Pro Plus Vers.  2016 (16.0.5095.1000)  MSO (16.0.5095.1000) 64-bit
Have not lately done installs.
https://www.msoutlook.info/question/200 shows older.

I did this:   Go to Control Panel > Programs.  Select Microsoft Office, click Change, Repair.  Restart PC, version same.  When Outlook opened, asked for password.

Created new profile.  Did not receive new message from my phone or from Outlook.

I still have the same problems.

Thanks for your help, and I still need suggestions.

Comment: Could this issue be reproduced on your web mail ?
Have you tried to close other program and run your Outlook in safe mode?

Also, in order to avoid the interference of Internet, it's suggested to close VPN or swith to other internet to check if the issue has any difference.

Comment: Working with my ISP, CenturyLink, I was able to send and receive with web mail.  Part of the problem is that it is somewhat intermittent.  For a while since opening it will receive messages, but not after that.  We also created a new email account for me, but the same problem. I will try safe mode now

Comment: Have you tried to test in safe mode and switch to other Internet? Does this issue has any update?

Comment: I do not use another internet provide to try it with, if that is what you mean.  The issue is the same.  The only other thing I can think of trying now is to uninstall Outlook 2016 and re-install it.  Do you know whether I would lose any of these things:  existing emails / folders, reminders, list of Junk addresses, Rules, settings - such as to not empty the Deleted Items when exiting Outlook?  Thanks.

Comment: I did try Safe mode, but it did not help.

Comment: Considering you are working with the older verison of Outlook, maybe you could first update the version of Outlook to check if the issue has any difference. Also, before you uninstall it, you could first try to repair your Outlook to test: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/repair-an-office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b.
For uninstall your client, I have tried to uninstall it via control panel in my pc, but the data file(.ost and .pst) wouldn't be deleted, I think the messages in your file may not be removed, but I couldn't ensure what would be removed after that.

Comment: I tried the repair but it did not fix the problem.  Then I uninstalled my Office 2016 Pro Plus and ran SetupProd_OffScrubOffice.exe do do a cleanup.  Then I reinstalled the same version, but still the problem.  I am reluctant to upgrade to Office 2019 because it is $440, even on Amazon.  Something changed a few weeks ago to cause this problem. I will be reviewing Add-Ins in Outlook.

Comment: How would I find out whether a Windows update caused this?  Is this the right place to ask this?

Comment: As I know, some 3rd-party programs may also cause some issue on Outlook, maybe you could try to perform a clean boot in Windows to check: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows-da2f9573-6eec-00ad-2f8a-a97a1807f3dd

Comment: I am having to post my comment in pieces due to its length.  I do want to give all the new information I have.

Comment: More info:

After a quite a number of times of Outlook failing, the following error messages were displayed.  I have already contacted my ISP, centurylink.net, and they were not able to help me.

It was based on the “operations timed out waiting” that I went in Outlook to
File > Account Settings > Account Settings > double clicked name on Email tab > More Settings > Advanced and increased the Server Timeouts from 1 minute to 10 minutes.  Outlook still had the same errors.

I did a clean boot in Windows to check: support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/…

I still have the same problems.

Comment: It said “1 of 5 Tasks completed successfully”

*Error Messages*
! Task ‘xxxx@centurylink.net - Sending' reported error (0x8004210B):
'The operation timed out waiting for a response from the sending (SMT) server. 
If you continue to receive this message, contact your server administrator or 
Internet service provider (ISP).'

Comment: !  Task ‘xxxx@centurylink.net - Receiving' reported error (0x8004210A):
‘ The operation timed out waiting for a response from the receiving (POP) server. 
lf you continue to receive this message, contact your server administrator or 
internet service provider (ISP)’ 

! Task ‘xxxx@centurylink.net - Receiving' reported error (0x8004210A): 
‘The operation timed out waiting for a response from the receiving (POP) server. 
If you continue to receive this message, contact your server administrator or 
Internet service provider (ISP).’

Comment: Have you checked the Windows update?

Comment: I looked at Windows Updates, but I did not really know what to look for.

Comment: What's the specific version of your Windows? In order to further confirm the issue, maybe you could also try to log in your account on other mail client(such as windows mail) to check if it could send/receive normally?

Comment: Microsoft Windows 10 Home, 10.0.19041  Build 19041

Comment: I logged into webmail.centurylink.net and was able to send/receive emails.  When I clicked on the Send/Receive icon in Outlook it received the message from webmail.  Part of the problem with the problems I am having is that it is intermittent.

Comment: I logged into Windows Mail, which I have never used before.  The most recent message received in it was from 1/11/21.  (Today is 2/12/21.)  I sent a message, but after about 10 minutes it still had not shown up in Send folder of Windows Mail or in Outlook, or on my phone.  Even when Outlook is not receiving messages without a restart, my phone always receives them on time.

webmail.centurylink.net had not received the message I sent in Windows Mail either.